# pos_label=1 is not a valid label

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, knn

A newly created column 'Y' has 'No' or 'Yes' values as outputs for a binary classification.
Getting the following error while trying to run a KNN classifier on the dataset.

> ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['No', 'Yes'], dtype='

Anybody has any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to it and post a sample of your data set?

Comment: So, what about `pos_label='Yes'`?